# Is there any way to get rowKey and patitionKey from Azure TableOperation?

Tags: c#, azure

I have a internal Azure TableOperation variable and I need to get rowKey and patitionKey. I know that I can do it by reflation but it the last way I would do.
I would be glad to find another way to get this info from TableOperation variable

```
foreach (TableOperation operation in tableOperations)
{
//I need to get RowKey in in this case from operation variable

results.Add(RetryManager.StorageRetryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() => table.Execute(operation)));
}
```

Comment: Share some code please if you can.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, using `TableOperation` it is not possible however `table.Execute` method return an object of type [`TableResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableresult.aspx). Now `TableResult` has a property called [`Result`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableresult.result.aspx). I tested with `Insert`, `Delete` and `InsertOrReplace` methods and in all of them `Result` contained the entity on which I performed the operation. Would this work for you?

```
        var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
        var tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
        var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("Address");
        var entity = new DynamicTableEntity("pk", "rk");
        entity.Properties.Add("Attribute1", new EntityProperty("Attribute 1 Value"));
        TableOperation upsertOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(entity);
        var tableResult = table.Execute(upsertOperation);
        var result = tableResult.Result;
        Console.WriteLine(result.GetType());//Prints Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity
        var deleteOperation = TableOperation.Delete(entity);
        tableResult = table.Execute(deleteOperation);
        result = tableResult.Result;
        Console.WriteLine(result.GetType());//Prints Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity
        var insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(entity, false);
        tableResult = table.Execute(insertOperation);
        result = tableResult.Result;
        Console.WriteLine(result.GetType());//Prints Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity
```

Comment: There is renaming issue with the solution. If the execute operation fails is there a way still to have entity information (rowKey, patitionKey) ?

Comment: I tried different ways to fetch this information but so far I haven't found a way to get the information about an entity in case the execute operation fails.